# IntelliJ inspection to find tags without 'id' attribute

Tags: jsf, intellij-idea, structural-search

I need to setup an inspection in IntelliJ that will find xhtml/html/jsf page elements without an `id attribute.

```
<h:outputText value="myOutputValue"
                        styleClass="someStyle"/>
<h:outputText value="myOtherOutputValue" />
```

I tried setting up a code inspection in intelliJ under "Structural search". With the following regexp however I can't configure it properly. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<(?:h:inputText|h:outputText)(?:\s+(?!id\b)[\w\-.:]+(?:\s*=\s*(?:"[^"]*"|'[^']*'|[\w\-.:]+))?)*\s*/?>
```

I know the regexp works because it will find the occurrences in my file when entered into the find box.

One last thing, in the end I'll want to expand `(?:h:inputText|h:outputText)` to include numerous tags so if using variables in the inspection or something else in intelliJ then that solution would be best. We want to make sure all developers put `id` attributes on all applicable page elements to aide in testing ease. (JSF tags are hideous)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a Structural Search pattern like the following:

```
<$name$ $id$>
```

Remember to set the correct file type. Click `Edit Variables...` and give *$name$* the following constraints:
Text/regexp: `h:inputText|h:outputText`

Give *$id$* the following constraints:
Text/regexp: `id`
Occurrences count: `0,0`

This will find all `<h:inputText>` and `<h:outputText>` tags without `id` attribute.

Comment: That worked wonderfully, I don't have enough of a rep to give the official vote. I read the documentation repeatedly and couldn't come up with the answer, docs aren't very clear. How did you learn/figure this out?

Comment: You should be able to just "accept" the answer. Structural Search is unfortunately quite complex and does not have a lot of documentation. It is possible to figure a lot of it out by looking carefully at all the built in *Existing Templates*. Or you can look at the source code and do development on SS&R for Jetbrains like I do;-)